# Problem with Python Implementation of Key Exchange part OTR Protocol

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, key-generation

Being new to software development and crypto in general, I thought I would write a simple p2p encrypted chat app using the otr protocol detailed here: https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/Protocol-v3-4.0.0.html

However, I am having an issue calculating g^x and g^y.

I have g =2 for a particular 1536-bit prime, as the protocol says. But when I try to calculate g**x, where x is a random 320 bit number (which I generate with random.getrandbits(320)), then python takes forever to calculate it.

Am I missing something important here? I realize I am trying to calculate an absolutely huge number, but I am absolutely confused because I think I am doing exactly what the protocol dictates. Can anyone point me in the right direction and give me some insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing that "All exponentiations are done modulo a particular 1536-bit prime".

See https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#pow.